# How to show data using Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in Angularjs. I want to show the list of customers after login. After login I get the access token which I want to save in cookie. When I am using `console.log(data)`, data is coming but in view page it is coming blank.

index.html

```
 <html lang="en" ng-app="customersApp">
<head>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.html">

    <title>Vizavoo</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--external css-->
   <link href="css/slidebars.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>

  <body>

   <div ng-view></div>



    <!-- js placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
       <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script> 
       <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-cookies.js"></script>
         <script src="app/app.js"></script>
         <script src="app/controllers/loginController.js"> </script>
           <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




  </body>

<!-- Mirrored from thevectorlab.net/flatlab/login.html by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2014], Mon, 08 Dec 2014 06:09:06 GMT -->
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function(window){

var app= angular.module('customersApp',['ngRoute','ngCookies']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            title: 'Login',
            controller: 'loginController',
               templateUrl: 'app/views/loginuser.html'
        })
            .when('/logout', {
                title: 'Logout',
                templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
                controller: 'loginController'
            })

            .when('/dashboard', {
                title: 'Dashboard',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/dynamic_table.html',
                controller: 'dashboard'
            })
            .when('/signup', {
                title: 'Signup',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/registration.html',
                controller: 'loginController'
            })

            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/login'
            });
  }]);
   window.app = app;

}(window));
```

loginController.js

```
app.controller('loginController', function ($scope,$http,$cookies,$cookieStore) {
    //initially set those objects to null to avoid undefined error
    $scope.login = {};
    $scope.signup = {};
    $scope.doLogin = function (customer) {


  $.post("http://54.173.65.120:2500/admin_login",
  {

     user_email : $scope.login.email,
      password : $scope.login.password

  },
  function(data,status){

      data = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(data);

//var accessToken = data.access_token;


    var someSessionObj = { 'accesstoken' : data.access_token};
   //console.log(someSessionObj);

    $cookies.dotobject = someSessionObj;
    $scope.usingCookies = { 'cookies.dotobject' : $cookies.dotobject, "cookieStore.get" : $cookieStore.get('dotobject') };

    $cookieStore.put('obj', someSessionObj);
    $scope.usingCookieStore = { "cookieStore.get" : $cookieStore.get('obj'), 'cookies.dotobject' : $cookies.obj, };

    console.log($cookieStore.get('obj').accesstoken);

     if(data.flag==10)
      {
          alert(data.error);
      }
      else
      {




         window.location.href = "#/dashboard";

      }


  });


    };

    $scope.logout = function () {
        Data.get('logout').then(function (results) {
            Data.toast(results);
            $location.path('login');
        });
    }


$scope.toggle = true;

    $scope.$watch('toggle', function(){
        $scope.toggleText = $scope.toggle ? 'Unblock' : 'Block';
        $scope.buttonStyle=$scope.toggle ? 'success' : 'danger';
    })


}); 

   app.controller('dashboard', function ($scope,$http,$cookies,$cookieStore) {
    var d = new Date()
var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
      console.log("in dash board");
    $.post('http://54.173.65.120:2500/customer_list',{

     access_token : $cookieStore.get('obj').accesstoken



  },function(data){

        console.log("hiiiii");
       console.log(data);
        var dataArray = [];
    //     console.log(data["aaData"]);
    //    console.log(data["aaData"].length);
        data = JSON.parse(data);




       data.forEach(function(column){

           var d = {

               user_id: "" ,
                user_name: "" ,
                email: "",
                mobile: "",
                created_at: "",
                is_block: "",


            };

             d.user_id = column.user_id;
            d.user_name = column.first_name+" "+column.last_name;

            d.email = column.email;
            d.mobile = column.mobile;
            d.created_at = column.created_at;            
            d.is_block = column.is_block;            


            console.log(d)
            dataArray.push(d);




       });         



   console.log(data);


        $scope.list = data;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
        $scope.entryLimit = 5; //max no of items to display in a page
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
    });
    $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    };
    $scope.filter = function() {
        $timeout(function() { 
            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
        }, 10);
    };
    $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };

});
 app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }




});
```

dynamic_table.html

```
 <!--common script for all pages-->
  <section id="container" class="">
      <!--header start-->
      <header class="header white-bg">
          <div class="sidebar-toggle-box">
              <div data-original-title="Toggle Navigation" data-placement="right" class="fa fa-bars tooltips"></div>
          </div>
          <!--logo start-->
          <a href="#/dashboard" class="logo" >Viza<span>Voo</span></a>

          <div class="top-nav ">
              <ul class="nav pull-right top-menu">
<!--                  <li>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control search" placeholder="Search">
                  </li>-->
                  <!-- user login dropdown start-->
                  <li><a href="#/login"><i class="fa fa-key"></i> Log Out</a></li>
                  <!-- user login dropdown end -->
<!--                  <li class="sb-toggle-right">
                      <i class="fa  fa-align-right"></i>
                  </li>-->
              </ul>
          </div>
      </header>
      <!--header end-->
      <!--sidebar start-->
      <aside>
          <div id="sidebar"  class="nav-collapse ">
              <!-- sidebar menu start-->
              <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">
                  <li>
                      <a href="#/dashboard">
                          <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                          <span>Customers</span>
                      </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="sub-menu">
                      <a href="javascript:;">
                          <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                          <span>Artists</span>
                      </a>
                      <ul class="sub">
                          <li><a  href="general.html">Verified</a></li>
                          <li><a  href="buttons.html">New Requests</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>

                  <li class="sub-menu">
                      <a href="javascript:;">
                          <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
                          <span>Services</span>
                      </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="sub-menu">
                      <a href="javascript:;" >
                          <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i>
                          <span>Sessions</span>
                      </a>
                      <ul class="sub">
                          <li><a  href="form_component.html">Upcoming</a></li>
                          <li><a  href="advanced_form_components.html">Past</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="sub-menu">
                      <a href="javascript:;">
                          <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
                          <span>Reports</span>
                      </a>
                  </li>
                 <li class="sub-menu">
                      <a href="javascript:;" >
                          <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
                          <span>Payment</span>
                      </a>
                  </li>

              </ul>
              <!-- sidebar menu end-->
          </div>
      </aside>
      <!--sidebar end-->
      <!--main content start-->
      <section id="main-content">
          <section class="wrapper">
              <!-- page start-->
              <div class="row" ng-controller="dashboard">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
              <section class="panel">
                  <div class="breadcrumbs">Home > <b>Customers</b></div>
              <header class="panel-heading">
                  Customers Table
              </header>


                  <div class="row" style="margin: 5px 0 0 0;">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <select ng-model="entryLimit" class="form-control">
                <option>5</option>
                <option>10</option>
                <option>20</option>
                <option>50</option>
                <option>100</option>
            </select> 
        </div>
                      <div class="col-md-3" style="float:right;">
            <input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-change="filter()" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" />
        </div>

    </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="adv-table">
              <table  class="display table table-bordered table-striped" id="dynamic-table">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th ng-click="sort_by('user_id')">S.No</th>
                  <th ng-click="sort_by('user_name')">Name</th>
                  <th ng-click="sort_by('mobile')">Phone No.</th>
                  <th ng-click="sort_by('email')">Email ID</th>
                  <th ng-click="sort_by('created_at')">Registration Date</th>
                  <th ng-click="sort_by('is_block')">Status</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit"  class="gradeX" >
                  <td>{{data.user_id}}</td>
                  <td>{{data.user_name}}</td>
                  <td>{{data.mobile}}</td>
                  <td>{{data.email}}</td>
                  <td>{{data.created_at}}</td>
                  <td>{{data.is_block}}</td>
<!--              <button type="button" class="btn btn-{{buttonStyle}}" ng-click="toggle = !toggle">{{toggleText}}</button>-->
              </tr>

              </tbody>

              </table>
              </div>
              </div>
              </section>
              </div>
              </div>

              <!-- page end-->
          </section>
      </section>

      <footer class="site-footer">
          <div class="text-center">
              2013 &copy; FlatLab by VectorLab.
              <a href="#" class="go-top">
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
              </a>
          </div>
      </footer>
      <!--footer end-->
  </section>
```

Where am I doing a mistake? Why data is not showing in view section?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `angular-cookie.js` as a module depedency in app.js...

```
var app= angular.module('customersApp',['ngRoute','ngCookies']);
```

Comment: how to get cookie from cookieStore as currently it shows error loginController.js:80 Object {error: "Some parameter missing.", flag: 0}

Comment: What is on line 80, for me it looks like data["aaData"]. Are you able to console.log this and see if 'aaData' key is in data?

Comment: sry this is the error Object {error: "Some parameter missing.", flag: 0}....please help me how to store and get access token in cookie after login so that i can show the customerdetails

Comment: Well from the code you have provided this error refers to line 80 which has nothing to do with $cookieStore....

Comment: To help you I have to see what this error is referring too, currently its not related to your original question. To answer you question of how to store a cookie try.... $cookies.obj = someSessionObj;

Comment: I have done the same please see the above code of loginController.js

Answer (score 0):

You missed a dependency for ngCookies:

```
var app= angular.module('customersApp',['ngRoute', 'ngCookies']);
```

I recommend using another style guide. It will be less messy than your current code. Check it here: https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide

Comment: can you please tell me how to get cookie from cookieStore

Comment: how to get cookie from cookieStore as currently it shows error loginController.js:80 Object {error: "Some parameter missing.", flag: 0}